# Windows 10 Forgetting Mapped Drives after Reboot

Tags: networking, windows-10, windows-8

We have a script that runs at logon and provides users with the relevant mapped network drives depending on certain variables. No issues with this on XP or 7.

On 8 and 10, after a reboot the mapped drives will be gone.

Even if I manually map these drives (ensuring reconnect at logon is ticked) they disappear after a reboot.

We need to look into mapping these with group policy but this might be further in the future than I would like to understand why our existing method isn't working.

Can anyone provide some insight into why this might be the case?

Comment: But if the script runs at logon why is this a problem? It would just remap the drives? Without information on how you do the mapping it could be kind of hard to answer, though it seems odd that even the manual mappings would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you have no network available at logon, this can cause issues with drive mappings (as the logon process does not always wait for the network). There is a group policy setting to wait for network before logon (check https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg486839.aspx and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2421599/ )

Secondly; if the script being called is running the 'net use' command without the persist command, the mapped drive will be removed on log off:

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]

Why not use GPO to map drives as you have a greater array of options.